# React Enzyme test: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme, provider

I'm getting blind, really.
Can someone tell me why the shallow doesn't work in this case and how to fix

I always get the error: **could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider**

```
import React from 'react';

import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
import { Box } from 'grommet';

// components
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar';
// import SidebarButton from '../Sidebar';

describe('<Sidebar />', () => {

  const wrapper = shallow(<Sidebar />);

  it('should work', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(Box).length).toBe(1);
  });

});
```

I always get the error: **could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Box, Button, Sidebar as SB, Nav, Text, Collapsible } from 'grommet';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { USERS, ORGS, ORDERS } from '../app/Routes';
import { Menu, Home, User, Group } from 'grommet-icons';
import { toggleSidebar } from '../features/SidebarSlice';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

/**
 * Renders static sidebar for all pages
 */
export default function Sidebar() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { sidebarOrgs } = useSelector((state) => state.sidebarDataSlice);
  const { isAdmin } = useSelector((state) => state.loginDataSlice);

  return (
    <Box>
      <SB round='small'>
        <Nav gap='small'>
          <SidebarButton
            icon={<Menu />}
            label='Menu'
            onClick={() => dispatch(toggleSidebar())}
          />

          {/* Organizations icons */}
          {sidebarOrgs.map(({ id, layer, name }) => (
            <Box key={id}>
              <SidebarButton
                icon={
                  layer !== 'Central' ? (
                    <img src={`./${layer}.svg`} alt={name} />
                  ):(
                    <Home className="homeIcon" />
                  )
                }
                label={`${layer}: ${name}`}
                route={ORDERS}
                layer={layer}
              />
            </Box>
          ))}
        </Nav>
      </SB>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an error from React-Redux, it is looking for a context. Are you using React-Redux?

Or you could put the code of your component Sidebar to have more context and try to help you.

**UPDATE**

Firstable, I would change the `shallow()` for `mount()`, due to `mount()` lets the complete representation of ReactDOM, a more realistic rendering.

I think the problem reason is when enzyme tries to render your component, your first lines of it, it gets information of Redux's store and this is the Provider that did not found it.
So...

```
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

/*And put this in your test*/
const wrapper = mount(
        <Provider store = {store}>
            <Sidebar  />
        </Provider>
);
```

The state of your store can be simulate with [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store). One exaple of this is:

```
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";

// Before your test, do next setting 
const middlewares = []; // If you are not using any middleware, leave the array empty or import it and put it in
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares); // Setting of store based on the middlewares.
const initState = {
     // Define test values of sidebarDataSlice and loginDataSlice
};
// Create the store to pass as prop in the <Provider>
const store = mockStore(initState);
```

This library just let create a "mock" of the state of your store, it does not update the state of it.
Hopefully this help you!